# I run the Kettle 8.3 source by intellij idea,Unable to instantiate class org.pentaho.di.engine.ui.RunConfigurationLifecycleListener

Tags: java, kettle

I run the Kettle 8.3 source by IntelliJ idea, unable to instantiate class `org.pentaho.di.engine.ui.RunConfigurationLifecycleListener`, java version is JDK8, I can use maven build install to successfully compile executable applications, but I can't run it by idea IDE directly.

```
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - ERROR (version Unknown, build 0 from 2019/05/06 14:32:32.256 by Administrator) : Unexpected error loading class for plugin 
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - ERROR (version Unknown, build 0 from 2019/05/06 14:32:32.256 by Administrator) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettlePluginException: 
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - Unable to instantiate class
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - org.pentaho.di.engine.ui.RunConfigurationLifecycleListener
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - 
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.loadClass(PluginRegistry.java:501)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.PropsUI.init(PropsUI.java:210)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.Props.<init>(Props.java:233)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.PropsUI.<init>(PropsUI.java:176)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.PropsUI.init(PropsUI.java:129)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:687)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.pentaho.di.engine.ui.RunConfigurationLifecycleListener
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.loadClass(PluginRegistry.java:496)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     ... 5 more
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.pentaho.di.engine.ui.RunConfigurationLifecycleListener.<init>()
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General -     ... 6 more
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - ERROR (version Unknown, build 0 from 2019/05/06 14:32:32.256 by Administrator) : Unexpected error loading class for plugin 
2019/05/06 14:33:03 - General - ERROR (version Unknown, build 0 from 2019/05/06 14:32:32.256 by Administrator) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettlePluginException: 
.
.
.
.
2019/05/06 14:33:26 - General - ERROR (version Unknown, build 0 from 2019/05/06 14:32:32.256 by Administrator) : Error starting Spoon shell
2019/05/06 14:33:26 - General - ERROR (version Unknown, build 0 from 2019/05/06 14:32:32.256 by Administrator) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2019/05/06 14:33:26 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.extension.ExtensionPointMap.callExtensionPoint(ExtensionPointMap.java:151)
2019/05/06 14:33:26 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.extension.ExtensionPointHandler.callExtensionPoint(ExtensionPointHandler.java:45)
2019/05/06 14:33:26 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9189)
2019/05/06 14:33:26 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:709)
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue, was a solution found for this ? I am trying to run Spoon.Java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282976/running-pentaho-spoon-ui-in-intellij

Answer (score 1):

Change maven in Project Settings to be same that you used to build it from command line. After that I've met different ClassNotFound exceptions but changing pom.xml in different modules allowed me to start Spoon through IDE

Comment: I am facing similar issue, I am trying to run Spoon.java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282976/running-pentaho-spoon-ui-in-intellij can you please elaborate this answer on how to resolve the issue and run spoon ui from intellij ?